# How can I input from a Greek keyboard into python dictionary and then print that same Greek text to the terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

I currently have English and Greek keyboards enabled on my Mac.  I'm writing a file that takes input from a user in both Greek and English and saves it in a dictionary.  When I print the dictionary to the terminal, how can I print the Greek text?  It works if I simply reprint it:

Python:

```
print('Please enter a greek word.')
i = input()
print(i)
```

Terminal:

```
Please enter a greek word.
'αγαπω'
αγαπω
```

But if I enter it to a dictionary first:

Python

```
word = {'greek':''}
print('Please enter a greek word')
word['greek'] = input()
print(word)
```

Terminal

```
Please enter a greek word.
'αγαπω'
{'greek': '\xce\xb1\xce\xb3\xce\xb1\xcf\x80\xcf\x89'}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't reproduce, need for details. `Please enter a greek word
αγαπω
{'greek': 'αγαπω'}`

Comment: Just discovered the issue.  I didn't realize python 2 was currently the default on my Mac.  Switched to python 3 and the issue resolved.  Thanks for testing the code!